# Comparing arrays structure

Tags: php, function

I have two arrays to compare and i don't know how to do this..
Here is my code:

```
$configStructure =
array('name'=>'Example','description'=>'Example','user'=>'Blabla');
```

this array(above) is the structure or the schema array of other configs.

```
$config =
array('name'=>'Application name','desc'=>'My description of app','user'=>'Alex');
```

I want to create a function that compares those arrays.

```
function checkStructure($configStructure, $config){
//the function, here will return false because the $config don't have the same structure of $configStructure(description is replace by desc)
}
```

Sorry if I my question is not grammatically correct, my English is not very good.
Thanks for help :)

Comment: Extract the keys for each array using array_keys() then do an array_diff()?

Comment: Hmm i think it will work, but if i have some optional values in my structure ?

Comment: Then you'd have to clarify exactly what you needed, and what rules you wanted to use for optional and mandatory values

Comment: I will probably write something if `array_diff` doesn't do what I need but ultimately I picture something that is itself an array, with keys `identical`, `in_a`, and `in_b` if we think of comparing array `a` to `b`.  To do it deep would require some thought, especially if the value for a given key in a is non-array, and in b is an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here another solution that only checks for the required keys:

```
$configStructure=array('name'=>'Example','description'=>'Example','user'=>'Blabla');
$config=array('name'=>'Application name','desc'=>'My description of app','user'=>'Alex');

function check($struct,$arr){
 foreach ($struct as $k => $v) if (!array_key_exists ($k,$arr)) return 0;
 return 1;
}
echo check($configStructure,$config);

// 0: the required keys ar **not** all there
// 1: all required keys are set
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use [`array_keys()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) — Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array
- [`array_diff()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) — Computes the difference of arrays

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkStructure($configStructure, $config) {
    if (array_diff(array_keys($configStructure), array_keys($config))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

$configStructure = array('name' => 'Example', 'description' => 'Example', 'user' => 'Blabla');
$config = array('name' => 'Application name', 'desc' => 'My description of app', 'user' => 'Alex');
```

`var_dump(checkStructure($configStructure, $config));` will return `bool(false)`.

Whereas changing `'desc'` to `'description'` will return `bool(true)`.

Comment: Ok and if i have some keys that are optionals ? and those are not required ?

Comment: It will return `true` only if the array structures are completely identical. Adding extra keys will return `false`. Also keep in mind this won't work with multidimensional arrays either.

Comment: @Alexandru this is possible to do , you will compare keys using loop and if key is not required , you continue , i would like to do it for you but i don't have enough time , maybe someone helps.

Answer (score 0):

please try this function.

```
function checkStructure($configStructure, $config) {
$arr_key1 = array_keys($configStructure);
$arr_key2 = array_keys(config);

if(count($arr_key1) != count($arr_key2)){
return false;
}

foreach($arr_key1 as $val){
if(!in_array($val,$arr_key2))
return false;
}
return true;
}
```